# Converting a String into Instance

Tags: lua, roblox

So.. I'm trying to Convert A string into a Roblox instance, like removing the "" from the string

I've tried the loadstring() but its giving me the error **loadstring() is not available**

Example:
`A = "Enum.Keycode.Up"` to `A = Enum.Keycode.Up`

I would appreciate if anyone could help

Comment: what should `loadstring` do here?  please refer to the Lua manual befor you attempt to blindly throw unknown functions at your problem

Comment: Try to iterate over all available enums (https://developer.roblox.com/en-us/api-reference/datatype/Enums) and then, when you found the enum you need, over the enum items to get the value (https://developer.roblox.com/en-us/api-reference/datatype/Enum)

Answer (score 0):

If your `Enum` table is global, then you can access it via `_G`:

```
Enum = {Keycode={Up="Test"}}
local A = "Enum.Keycode.Up"
local function get_value(a)
    local ret = _G
    for v in a:gmatch("([^%.]+)") do
        if not ret[v] then return nil end
        ret = ret[v] 
    end  
    return ret
end
print (get_value(A)) -- Test
```

Comment: the thing is.. Enum is not a custom table I made.. its a built in function-like table..

Comment: so does the code work or not? maybe `Enum` is not available in this place?

Comment: The code only retrives nil value